# Xamarin Forms. Pass ViewModel parameter to converter

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, binding, ivalueconverter

I am trying to pass a variable defined inside the viewmodel to a custom converter.

This is the xaml file:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converter:IsLastItemConverter x:Key="lastItemConverter" Collection="{Binding Selfies}" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<ContentPage.Content>
    ....
    <local:Selfie IsLastItem="{Binding ID, Converter={StaticResource lastItemConverter}}" />
    ....
</ContentPage.Content>
```

This is the xaml.cs code behind

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class SelfieWall : BaseContentPage
{
    public SelfieWall()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new SelfieWallViewModel();
    }
}
```

This is the ViewModel

```
public class SelfieWallViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   ....
   public List<Model.Selfie> Selfies { get; set; }
   ....
}
```

This is the converter

```
public class IsLastItemConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public List<Selfie> Collection { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
                              object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

When I try to load the view defined in the above xaml I get the error

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

The error disappears if I remove

```
Collection="{Binding Selfies}"
```

from the XAML.

Any hints on how to pass the variable of the ViewModel to the converter.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/#Bindings_and_Collections

Comment: I read that link but there is no mention on how to bind from viewmodel to converter.

Comment: You have to set the BindingContext. Post your ViewModel and your full XAML... you should define your converte in XAML like <local:DoubleToIntConverter x:Key="intConverter" />. What is Collection="{Binding Selfies}"??

Comment: See my edited post

Answer (score 0):

If I have understand correctly, you would like to know if your item in `Selfies` is the last or not. I think you can't do this with IValueConverter. I suggest to use a Property in your `Model.Selfie` that you set each time you Add / Remove an Item from your Collection.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Xamarin.Forms does not support Converter Parameter binding with ViewModel properties. It only accepts values passed directly from UI/Xaml.

Here is a workaround for that.

```
public class BindablePropertyObject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Populate converter parameter with this object.
    /// Pass element reference as SOURCE and binding PROPERTY NAME.
    /// Gets the binding context of SOURCE and property with the same name as PROPERTY NAME from the binding context.
    /// Gets value of the property fetched from binding context.
    /// Ex: Write in element ConverterParameter={utils:BindablePropertyObject PropertyName=property name, Source= {x:Reference element name}}
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Returns value of the property</returns>
    public object GetValueFromPropertyType()
    {
        if (Source.IsNotNull() && Source is View view && view.BindingContext.IsNotNull())
        {
            var property = view.BindingContext.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName);
            if (property.IsNotNull())
            {
                return property.GetValue(view.BindingContext);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Name of property which is binded to view 
    /// </summary>
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// XF element which will be used to get binding context.
    /// </summary>
    public object Source { get; set; }
}
```

Using this you can create a object in your Xaml file and pass Source and Property Name. The GetValueFromPropertyType() will then fetch the property and it's value from Source.BindingContext since Source will of type XF. View.